# Django Compressor not using STATICFILES_FINDER from settings

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-staticfiles, django-compressor

I'm trying to use [Django Compressor](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which seems pretty straight-forward, but for some reason I keep getting an error, specifically:

> When using Django Compressor together with staticfiles, please add 'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder' to the STATICFILES_FINDERS setting

My *settings.py* file includes the following:

```
DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
    'compressor',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDER = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder'
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '_static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
```

I'm not sure if this is a compatibility issue with Django 1.10 (Django Compressor changelog states it is compatible with 1.10), or if Django Compressor simply is broken, since I've clearly added 'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder' to the STATICFILES_FINDERS setting. I've also tried with *DEBUG=False*.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: STATICFILES_FINDERS. You are missing the final S.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides Thanks, always good to have a separate set of eyes. If you'd have added your comment as an answer I'd have upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

You just miss letter S in end of the SETTINGS VARIABLES. Just change

***STATICFILES_FINDER -> STATICFILES_FINDERS***